# How to put default img Url if curent failed to load

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I'm using regular img:

`<img border="0" title="Sterling Silver Jesus Name Necklace" src="http://www.myengravedjewelry.com/images/products/101-01-071-02_medium.jpg" alt="0">`

I just want to put another url in case if this one is failed to load
of some how to check if this url is bad than change it (with javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use attribute onerror

```
<img src="bad_src.jpg" onerror="this.src='good_src.jpg'">
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use method like this

javascript

```
function img404(img) {
    img.onerror = "";
    img.src = "default.jpg";
    return true;
}
```

html

```
<img src="image.png" onerror="img404(this);"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no such methods in HTML. You can control from some back end language like PHP.

Something like:

```
if(!file_exists($filepath)) {
    $src = 'http://site.com/def.jpg';
}
```

Moreover, use proper image description in ALT tag or image.

Comment: and in asp.net javascript?